# Differential geometry applied to dynamical systems

Tags: differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, complex-systems

Im a geometry and complexity student, and am compiling a reading list of resources discussing real world applications of differential geometry in dynamical systems.

I have ordered a book by Jean-Marc Ginoux called [Differential Geometry Applied to Dynamical Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814277142), yet am wondering what other helpful texts there might be out there.

Ideally, I'd love a resource that leans more in the direction of coded examples as opposed to theory, but am open to all suggestions.